# Highcharts - Display only one name at each end of the bar's chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to display only one name at each end of the bar's chart.
I send data from a controller (i am using zend) :

```
$chartsData['project'][] = array('riri', 45);
$chartsData['project'][] = array('fifi', 120);
$chartsData['project'][] = array('loulou', 3);
```

And I got this:

[image]

As you can see, everything is fine and the data are correct. Except the name at the end of the bar. I just want to show one name each bar (riri, fifi, loulou). Presently, i got this in my js file :

```
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                color : '#4572A7',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    format: '{series.name}' 
                }
            }
        },
```

I try to change the value in `{series.name}` to put `{x}` or `{y}` but i only got the number.

Comment: Generally how you output series array looks like? Because it seems that data is has no correct form. In array you should have x/y values, but in your you use names.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell if you've actually set correct values within `xAxis` or `yAxis` or `series`, but if you have, you need to use `formatter`. Try this:

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.x;
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Here's an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jr79Y/

Comment: I try it; but i got this : [Screenshoot](http://i40.tinypic.com/bi07j7.png). And just for knowing, i set my xAxis and yAxis like that :

Comment: did you try `return this.y;` instead?

Comment: Yes, and i got 45,120,3. But if i change the `xAxis` like that :
`xAxis: {
                categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                labels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            },`
I got this : [Screenshoot](http://i43.tinypic.com/2mdicu9.jpg)
Do you know how i can change the values of `'Africa', 'America', 'Asia'` with the data i send before in my controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the answer to my problem :

```
            plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                color : '#4572A7',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.point.name;
                    } 
                }
            }
        },
```

I just replace `this.x` to `this.point.name`. I hope it will help somebody. Thanks all for your help and time.